# can't get wordPress's admin-post.php to work

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

I've reviewed several online docs on this as well as reviewed the post's on this site but still can't seem to get my admin-post requests to work. In my admin menu constructor I add the following actions:

add_action('admin_post_modify_release_request', 'handle_release_posting');

with the following function for the handler:

```
function handle_release_posting(){
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "<br/>incoming:" . var_export($_POST, TRUE) . "<br/>";
    ?> <div class="wrap">
        <?php screen_icon(); ?>
            <div class="release_response">Posting response goes here.</div> 
       </div>
        <?php 
}​
```

My html form element  is this:
    " method="post"> 
                ​

with other inputs plus...

```
 <input type="hidden" id='action' name="action" value="modify_release_request">
      <input type="submit" value="Modify Release"></div>
     </form>
```

​
The behavior on submission of the request is to call http://joomla.tenasys.lan/wp-admin/admin-post.php

with a completely empty page:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
​
```

What Have I missed? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sorry I see the form element didn't post:

Comment: <form id="sdk_release_meta_data" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>" method="post">

Answer (score 5):

Somehow I have not managed to use hidden input to pass action parameter, like this:

The alternative solution was add action parameter in URL as this:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
    <form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>?action=add_foobar" method="post">
```

#### Here is whole solution:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
function sandbox_show_plugin(){
    global $post;
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>?action=add_foobar" method="post">
      <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter email">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <?php

}

//Hooks
add_shortcode( 'sandbox_plugin_shortcode', 'sandbox_show_plugin' );


function prefix_admin_add_foobar(){ 
    status_header(200);
    var_dump($_POST);
    // wp_redirect( 'http://any.url/',302 ); 
    die("Server received '{$_POST['name']}' from your browser.");

}

add_action( 'admin_post_add_foobar', 'prefix_admin_add_foobar' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_add_foobar', 'prefix_admin_add_foobar' ); // this is for non logged users
```

Comment: I had a similar issue, in my case it was a form with a very large amount of fields. After moving the hidden action + nonce fields to begin of form, the issue went away. Though some fields towards the end of form were still truncated in the requests. The PHP `max_input_vars` option truncated the POST fields processed by PHP at 1000 while the overall number of fields was much higher (~4000).